# cache overflow with realurl and tx_cal

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

Configuration: TYPO3 7.6.30, tx_cal 1.11.1, realurl 2.1.8

Problem: the realurl table tx_realurl_urlcache gets bigger and bigger with millions of entries and the whole system slows down extremely until I truncate the table.

It seems that is the case because the urls for single events contains the chash. They looks like this:

```
detailansicht/cal/event///tx_cal_phpicalendar//carmine-abate-der-huegel-des-windes/?tx_cal_controller%5Byear%5D=2018&tx_cal_controller%5Bmonth%5D=12&tx_cal_controller%5Bday%5D=13&cHash=c9eebc60256d7201b969e975ee151d94
```

Any idea whats going wrong here? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be that search engines follow all your links and any repeated events will result in indefinite further 'pages'.

Try to restrict the spidering with no-follow / no-index directives. at least for dates more than x month in future/past.
Otherwise restrict visibility of such events at all.